# How to Transfer data between my My personal Chatbot to Microsoft Team

Tags: chatbot, microsoft-teams

How can I connect My chatbot(which provides REST API to third part application) to Microsoft Team.

Step 1: User Input the message in to Microsoft Team. This message should be passed to my chatbot (Message Should be sent as API)

Step 2 : My Chatbot will return the processed output to the Microsoft Team, and message should be displayed in the team.

Answer (score 0):

You can [create a bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-create) and add Microsoft Teams as a channel. You would receive the payload with user entered text message which you can use for your processing. You can then reply back either in plain text message or [card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/cards/cards-reference) formats.

Please have a look at [Outgoing webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/outgoingwebhook) in Microsoft Teams as well.

Comment: Thanks for providing the information, I have used the Outgoing Webhooks concept and create a outgoing webhooks and Got the secreat key, when i came back to the my channel, i can see the message that Mr,xxx has added ITBot to the Team message, but however when i try to type @ITBot, Its not working.

Comment: What exactly happening? Are you not receiving message to your code?